# Flexbox - control space between span and text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got two types of buttons:

1. Buttons where `span` is the first child
2. Buttons where `span` is the last child

I'd like to control the space between the span and text - without adding more HTML or classes. Is it possible?

Using pseudo selectors `:first-child` or `:last-child` won't work because `span` is always the first and the last child.

```css
button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>X</span>
  Remove
</button>

<button>
  Remove
  <span>X</span>
</button>
```

**Edit**: To be clear, I only want to control the space between the text and the span. So, when the span is first the there should be a right margin. When the span is last the should be a left margin.

**Edit 2**: AND I'd like to keep flexbox because of flexibility.

Comment: You should replace inline-flex to inline if you want X and remove on same line http://jsfiddle.net/gngrdj11/

Comment: @CY5 I'd like to keep using flexbox, because it adds flexibility, e.g. multiple lines.

Comment: The main problem is you actually don't have 2 cases, you always have a button with just a span in, that it's behind or in front of some text doesn't change anything because the text ain't wrapped in an element

Comment: In both of your examples, the `<span>` element **is the first child** based on the virtue that the text node is not wrapped by another element.

Comment: All of these what ifs and no one getting results but me. OP > To be clear, I only want to control the space between the text and the span. So, when the span is first the there should be a right margin. When the span is last the should be a left margin.

Comment: @zer00ne Your solution breaks when a new button is added side by side with the other buttons.

Comment: @NinjaFart Explain to me how it is broken I just added 6 buttons take a look.

Comment: @zer00ne I want all of the buttons to have space between `text` and `span`.

Comment: @NinjaFart you need a flex container over everything you want to work as a flex item meaning extra markup. Flexbox does not work like position or float

Comment: @NinjaFart Not willing to add a class is not flexible nor is it sensible. Using flexbox without additional markup is pointless as well. The criteria you have is not very productive. Flexibility is adapting to reach a goal by any and all tools available.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the problem with the question is that it's impossible with the criteria you set. You are trying to style elements differently that are exactly the same from a css perspective. Both 'versions' are just a `<span/>` inside a `<button/>`, the fact that there is text inside the button and that it's positioned before/after the span has no effect on any css rules.

You will either get a very inflexible solution (i.e. selecting each element manually by using `nth-child()` or something similiar). Or you will have to change your markup. For changing your markup you either add classes to the spans, or you wrap the text in an element (p for example). How it would work with classes is quite straightfoward, by wrapping text you could use `first-child` and `last-child` pseudo-selectors properly, like so

```css
button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span:first-child{
    margin-right:20px;
}

span:last-child{
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>X</span>
  <p>Remove</p>
</button>

<button>
  <p>Remove</p>
  <span>X</span>
</button>

<button>
  <span>X</span>
  <p>Remove</p>
</button>

<button>
  <p>Remove</p>
  <span>X</span>
</button>
```

Comment: FINALLY! Another voice of reason!

Comment: @DrunkWolf Not the solution I wanted, but the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: @NinjaFart Sorry I didn't sugar coat my answer.

Answer (score -1):

<s>You can do this by adding :</s>

```
// Span last child
span:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

// Span first child
span:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

To your `First-child-span` ou your `Last-child-span` button type. Without adding a class to these two types of button I don't think this would be possible.

**EDIT :**

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>X</span>
  Remove
</button>

<button>
  Remove
  <span>X</span>
</button>
<button>
  Remove
  <span>X</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right way, he wants to check wether the `span` is the first/last child **inside** the button, you are checking if the button is the first/last child inside another element...

Comment: OP > To be clear, I only want to control the space between the text and the span. So, when the span is first the there should be a right margin. When the span is last the should be a left margin. I believe my solution meets those demands as for OP wanting to check what's what, that would be an ends to a need not the solution itself.

Comment: I don't think your solution is the best because if you add a third button, it becomes a mess ! The margin doesn't remains the same.

Comment: both of the answer has removed inline-flex from button read 2nd comment what OP say " I'd like to keep using flexbox, because it adds flexibility, e.g. multiple lines"

Comment: OP > To be clear, I only want to control the space between the text and the span. So, when the span is first the there should be a right margin. When the span is last the should be a left margin. >When has it become that the OP's request not the goal?

Comment: How's it a mess?I just added 6 more buttons and the first and last are the same

Comment: Yes, first and last are the same, but not the others !! And here is the problem !

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée Look again.